# Do PS2 emulators support joypads with varying button sensitivity

Tags: emulation, ps2

The PS2 joy-pads had variable button sensitivity. For example, in MGS3, slightly holding the square was used for aiming, and pressing it all the way to the end meant *shoot*. Does any Playstation 2 emulator support such joy-pads in a reliable/accurate manner?

I am asking this in the scope of the aforementioned MGS3 which I'd like to replay again and I remember that playing on a cheap, unoriginal pad was a pain.

Comment: Hi Maurycy, The first question you have there is mostly a shopping recommendation/list question and is off-topic as defined by our [faq]. The emulator question, though, is completely on topic. You might want to edit your question to focus on support for that and assume that there are controllers that have support if emulators do :)

Comment: @Ktash Thanks, I've changed the first part a bit - do you think it is okay now? If not, I'll just chop away the whole section then.

Comment: You're still asking multiple questions in one. One being a terminology question, the other being an emulation question. It might be better to break them down into their own separate questions.

Comment: @Fluttershy 'Kay then, fair enough.

Comment: [PCSX2 seems to with Lilypad](http://forums.pcsx2.net/Thread-Gamepad-pressure-sensitive-buttons) but it also looks like it isn't well supported by gamepads. The PS3 DualShock 3 controller is recommended on that post.